# Sub query returning all values and then applying where condition

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I am having an issue with a query only in one particular environment/database even if the data is almost similar. Here is the simplified scenario:

Table A - One column - Id (long)

```
Id
1
2
3
```

Table B - Two columns - value(varchar) and field2(varchar)

```
  Value Field2
1)abc   NotKey
2)Test  NotKey
3)1     Key
4)1.56  NotKey
```

When I run the query

```
select * from table a
where id in(select value from table b where Field2 = 'Key')
```

I get the error

Result: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'abc' (earlier I had this value erraneously as 'NotKey') to data type int.

on one database. In three other databases, the value returns correctly as "1".

I am using SQL Server 2008. What might be the issue here?

Comment: What is the result of select value from tableb where Field2 = 'Key'

Comment: That gives only the third record.

Comment: I made a correction to the question "Result: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'abc' (earlier I had this value erraneously as 'NotKey') to data type int."

Comment: can you try to get the error in the jsfiddle? I am pretty shure that the sample data is not right. It works in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e9223/24

Comment: I will try to replicate it jsfiddle, but I am not confident that I can replicate it.

Comment: Additionally, I took a back of the database on the offending server and restored it onto a different instance/machine and the query works. I am even more confused now. :/

Comment: Sounds like a Server Collation issue, but that cant be an issue with the data you supplied.It would need some differences depending on Upercase  / Lowercase values

Comment: I tried replicating the error in sqlfiddle, but that did not happen. I got in around 400 actual records from my database and inserted them and sqlfiddle did not even work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave the wrong filter for the filter that leads to the error.

The errror only happens when you select:

```
select * from tablea
where id in(select value from tableb where Field2 = 'NotKey')
```

You have to cast one of the columns

```
select * from tablea
where cast( id as nvarchar(20)) in(select value from tableb where Field2 = 'NotKey')
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e9223/23

Comment: No, what I mentioned in my post is how it is happening. Ideally the error should be thrown when I execute your first query which is what I would expect it to do.
As far as the cast goes, yes that is the work around I have, but I am trying to understand why the error is occurring with the scenario that I provided.

Comment: Its is because the query matches an int column (id) to an  varchar column (value ), which is only allowed when every item in value realy is an int (check rules for implicit conversion in sql-sever)

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't the conversion to int be done on the resultant set of the sub query? As I see, it is being done to records that don't satisfy the where condition as well.

Comment: That would not work for your data. You cant cast all items in value to int

Comment: Correct, so my expectation was the conversion is applied only to the result set of the sub query. If that is not the case, I am fine with modifying my query to make it work correctly. 

But what I am trying to understand is, the same error should occur in other instances of the database on other SQL Servers which is not happening. On those instances I get the correct value "1" as the result.

Answer (score 1):

You must have a record in this instance that doesn't follow the same pattern as before.  Try running the following query to find your bad data.  You could either fix the record or add a numeric check to the query you're using.

```
select *
from table
where Field2 = 'Key'
    and (ISNUMERIC(Value) = 0
        OR CHARINDEX('.', Value) > 0);
```

Filtered query:

```
select *
from table a
where id in
(
    select value
    from table b
    where Field2 = 'Key'
        and ISNUMERIC(value) = 1
        and CHARINDEX('.', Value) = 0
);
```

Comment: Adding the ISNUMERIC solved my issue, as would have changing my query to "select * from table a
where convert(varchar, id) in(select value from table b where Field2 = 'Key')"

Comment: I have added one more entry to the second table with the value 1.56 which is what causing my original issue and it would pass the isnumeric filter but the query will fail because it cannot be converted to int/long which is what the id in Table A is.

Comment: If you convert your ID, make sure SQL Server is still using your indexes properly.  I don't believe that conversion is deterministic so SQL Server will not be able to use existing indexes.